# Code works fine on "php" but it does not when using Ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I am writing code for an on-line store for computing equipment.The site allows an Administrator to add, edit or delete to a database some categories of equipment such as Computers, Displays, Mouses, etc.
The code works fine to add, edit and delete categories when is solely written on PHP.

Then, to delete categories, I tried with Ajax to prevent reloading the page and it does not work: it does not seem to call the delete function (called "eliminar" as it is in Spanish) and I don't understand why. I would appreciate any help provided. Here is the part of the code that is relevant to this problem:

PART A): EVERYTHING WORKS FINE, CODE USING PHP ONLY:
CODE ELIMINATES CATEGORIES FROM THE DATA BASE AS IT SHOULD:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function eliminar(id) {
   if(confirm("Category will be eliminated. Please confirm")) {
   location.href="eliminarcategorias.php?idcategoria="+id;
   }
}
</script>
```

CODE ON FILE "eliminarcategorias.php", ALSO WORKING FINE ALONG WITH PREVIOUS CODE:

```
<?php 
session_start();

if (isset($_SESSION['administrador'])) {
    $idcategoria=$_GET['idcategoria'];
    include('../../php/conexion.php');  //ROUTING TO CONNECT TO MYSQL
    mysql_query("delete from categorias where id='$idcategoria'");
    cerrarconexion();                   //CLOSES ACCESS TO MYSQL
    header('location:formaniadircategorias.php'); //RETURNS TO MAIN PAGE
}

else {
    header('location:../index.html');
    }
?>
```

PART B): CHANGES ADDING CODE ON AJAX DOES NOT WORK: IT DOES NOT SEEM TO CONNECT WITH THE FUNCTION "eliminar" AND IT DOES NOT DELETE RECORDS FROM THE DATA BASE.
IT IS WORTH TO MENTION THAT THE MESSAGE "Category will be eliminated. Please confirm" IS DISPLAYED BUT THEN NOTHING HAPPENS AND RECORDS ARE NOT DELETED.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function eliminar(id) {
   if(confirm("Category will be eliminated. Please confirm")) {

     $.ajax({
        type:"POST",  
        url:"eliminarcategorias.php",
        data:'idcategoria='+id,
     })

   }
}
</script>
```

CODE ON "eliminarcategorias.php", WITH MINOR CHANGES TO SUIT THE CODE ADDED IN AJAX...

```
<?php 
session_start();

if (isset($_SESSION['administrador'])) {
    $idcategoria=$_POST['idcategoria'];
    include('../../php/conexion.php');  //ROUTING TO CONNECT TO MYSQL
    mysql_query("delete from categorias where id='$idcategoria'");
    cerrarconexion();                   //CLOSES ACCESS TO MYSQL

}

else {
    header('location:../index.html');
    }
?>
```

Comment: Please stop using deprecated+removed `mysqli_*` version. Try to update to PHP7 along with `mysqli_*` Or `PDO` library

Comment: please write `error_reporting(-1); and ini_set("display_errors", true);` before session start and then check in console ajax call response for errors

Comment: Along with switching to PDO, [prepared statements](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) should be used, especially when using user input in a query to avoid [SQL injection](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/SQL_Injection) attacks. Even if you stick with MYSQLi (you shouldn't, it's deprecated and will go away eventually), you can still [use prepared statements with `mysqli`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php). Your site **WILL** be hacked eventually if you don't protect yourself from injection attacks.

Comment: Have you checked the server logs? Do you see a POST request being made for `eliminarcategorias.php` in the correct directory? If you don't see a request it could be a problem with the JS, check the developer console to see if there are any error messages there. If there is a request, for the correct URL, check the PHP log files to see if there are any error messages there that might help figuring it out.

Comment: @Useless Code, thanks so much for your recommendations. I followed them and after spending some time I found my error: I had a duplicated script that called the jquery twice:                                                          
- first as: <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>

- then as:  <script src="../../javascript/jquery-slim.min.js"></script>  -->. I removed this last one and everything works fine now!!

Answer (score 2):

Your data syntax for ajax is wrong. It should be like this:

```
<script>
function eliminar(id) {
   if(confirm("Category will be eliminated. Please confirm")) {

     $.ajax({
        type:"POST",  
        url:"eliminarcategorias.php",
        data:{idcategoria:id }
     })

   }
}
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks. I changed my syntax to match yours and still it does not work; nothing happens, records are not deleted.

Comment: Thanks @Alive to Die for your suggestion to update to PHP7 or PDO library. Since my project is just a prototype not intended to go into production and I have invested a lot of time on coding, I would like to continue using what I have. So I would appreciate any suggestion to fix my current problem: why is it that the code works fine except when changed to Ajax?

Comment: Thanks @Useless Code for your concerns on security and suggestion to change and use PDO library. My project is just a prototype not intended to go into production. When it goes into production (if it does) I will change to PDO and Prepared Statements. For right now, I would like to continue using what I have. Any ideas on why the code works fine on PHP but not on Ajax?

Answer (score 0):

I had these two statements on the  section:

```
<script src="../../javascript/jquery-slim.min.js"></script>
```

The problem was fixed by removing the last one!